# Static Image Background Subtraction

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to do background subtraction on static images of faces (extract the face), but the only OpenCV tutorials I can find are for video.

I understand that background is easier to identify from a video, but are there any approaches for photos?

Comment: Can you give us a little more context? What do you plan to do with the foreground once you have it? I did look at a skin colour model to do the job, but I suspect you might need to look at more modern face detectors.

Comment: I am looking to analyze skin color, hair color, and other body features.  Technically the picture may be of the whole body

Comment: The background in videos is easy to identify since it can be defined as the object that varies little in the video, that is to say it is a static or quasi-static object, to obtain this, the frames are analyzed, and areas where there is little variation. But in the case of photographs it is difficult, and I would say impossible if we do not define that it is a background, for example in a photograph could have a wall and could be part of the background, but if it is actually a table that moves, would be part of the fund.

Comment: I recommend you go the other way, for example make a skin filter, or use face detection algorithms.

Comment: @eyllanesc this seems like it will be the best approach

Comment: If you are going to work with the whole body, look into human pose estimation. However, many popular approaches use depth sensors.

Answer (score 0):

`Haar Cascade` is widely used in that purpose. It is good to detect human face, but hardly used to classify who it is.

Here is nice reference : https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/d7/d8b/tutorial_py_face_detection.html